# jQuery Selecting one of multiple elements with the same class

Tags: jquery, class, if-statement, selector

Trying to write a simple script that will change the background color of an element with a certain class (.global__image-outer-wrap--game-medium) if an "a" within another class and also parent of both (.giveaway__row-outer-wrap) has a certain class (giveaway__column--group) in case when there's multiple elements with (.giveaway__row-outer-wrap).

```
if ( $(".giveaway__row-outer-wrap,a").hasClass("giveaway__column--group") ){
   $(.global__image-outer-wrap--game-medium").css("background-color", "limegreen")};
```

TL;DR Multiple elements with the same class; I need to select only the ones in which "a" has a certain class.

HTML of the site I'm trying to apply the script to

```
<div class="giveaway__row-outer-wrap">
  <div class="giveaway__row-inner-wrap">
    <div class="giveaway__summary">
      <h2 class="giveaway__heading">
        <a class="giveaway__heading__name" href="/giveaway/fteQx/fahrenheit-indigo-prophecy-remastered">Fahrenheit: Indigo Prophecy Remastered</a><span class="giveaway__heading__thin">(10P)</span><a class="giveaway__icon" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://store.steampowered.com/app/312840/"><i class="fa fa-steam"></i></a><i data-popup="popup--hide-games" data-game-id="3962555" class="giveaway__icon giveaway__hide trigger-popup fa fa-eye-slash"></i>
      </h2>
      <div class="giveaway__columns">
        <div><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <span title="Today, 11:59pm">1 minute remaining</span></div><div class="giveaway__column--width-fill text-right"><span title="February 16, 2015, 4:03pm">4 days ago</span> by <a class="giveaway__username" href="/user/UraniumFalconPunch">UraniumFalconPunch</a></div><a href="/giveaway/fteQx/fahrenheit-indigo-prophecy-remastered/groups" class="giveaway__column--group"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i></a></div>
      <div class="giveaway__links">
        <a href="/giveaway/fteQx/fahrenheit-indigo-prophecy-remastered/entries"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> <span>10 entries</span></a>
        <a href="/giveaway/fteQx/fahrenheit-indigo-prophecy-remastered/comments"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> <span>10 comments</span></a>
      </div>
    </div><a href="/user/UraniumFalconPunch" class="global__image-outer-wrap global__image-outer-wrap--avatar-small"><div class="global__image-inner-wrap" style="background-image:url(https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/ef/ef653aea58e8709fd6e13f5fa2b39e3fe7b8e5a9_medium.jpg);"></div></a><a class="global__image-outer-wrap global__image-outer-wrap--game-medium" href="/giveaway/fteQx/fahrenheit-indigo-prophecy-remastered"><div class="global__image-inner-wrap" style="background-image:url(http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/312840/capsule_184x69.jpg);"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's multiple divs with giveaway_row-outer-wrap class but not all have "a" elements with giveaway__column-group class.

Comment: `$('a.giveaway__row-outer-wrap')` ?

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing your requirement. Can you post some HTML and say which elements should be selected?

Comment: Added the HTML. This is so chaotic that even I get lost in what I want. Basically, there's multiple divs with giveaway__row-outer-wrap, inside these divs there's 2 important for me divs: giveaway__columns which sometimes has the "a" with class giveaway__column--group and global__image-outer-wrap--game-medium which is responsible for the style of the element I'm trying to alter.

Comment: I don't see `giveaway__column-group` in your HTML. So it's hard to tell if my answer actually works.

Comment: `giveaway__column--group` Sorry, forgot about the second "-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.has()` to select elements that contain elements matching a selector.

```js
$(".giveaway__row-outer-wrap").has("a.giveaway__column--group").each(function() {
  $(".global__image-outer-wrap--game-medium", this).css("background-color", "limegreen")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="giveaway__row-outer-wrap">
  <div class="giveaway__row-inner-wrap">
    <div class="giveaway__summary">
      <h2 class="giveaway__heading">
            <a class="giveaway__heading__name" href="/giveaway/fteQx/fahrenheit-indigo-prophecy-remastered">Fahrenheit: Indigo Prophecy Remastered</a><span class="giveaway__heading__thin">(10P)</span><a class="giveaway__icon" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://store.steampowered.com/app/312840/"><i class="fa fa-steam"></i></a><i data-popup="popup--hide-games" data-game-id="3962555" class="giveaway__icon giveaway__hide trigger-popup fa fa-eye-slash"></i>
          </h2>
      <div class="giveaway__columns">
        <div><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>  <span title="Today, 11:59pm">1 minute remaining</span>
        </div>
        <div class="giveaway__column--width-fill text-right"><span title="February 16, 2015, 4:03pm">4 days ago</span> by <a class="giveaway__username" href="/user/UraniumFalconPunch">UraniumFalconPunch</a>
        </div><a href="/giveaway/fteQx/fahrenheit-indigo-prophecy-remastered/groups" class="giveaway__column--group"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="giveaway__links">
        <a href="/giveaway/fteQx/fahrenheit-indigo-prophecy-remastered/entries"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> <span>10 entries</span></a>
        <a href="/giveaway/fteQx/fahrenheit-indigo-prophecy-remastered/comments"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> <span>10 comments</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="/user/UraniumFalconPunch" class="global__image-outer-wrap global__image-outer-wrap--avatar-small">
      <div class="global__image-inner-wrap" style="background-image:url(https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/ef/ef653aea58e8709fd6e13f5fa2b39e3fe7b8e5a9_medium.jpg);"></div>
    </a>
    <a class="global__image-outer-wrap global__image-outer-wrap--game-medium" href="/giveaway/fteQx/fahrenheit-indigo-prophecy-remastered">
      <div class="global__image-inner-wrap" >This should be lime green</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've got it working, although it doesn't look right. When I examine the DOM in the console, I see the `background-color` style, but it doesn't look green.

Comment: I didn't have all the underscores before.